# I could see my device skin in Android Studio

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, ubuntu-16.04, android-virtual-device

In previous versions Android Studio I could see the device's skin at layout editor, now (Android Studio 2.3.3) i cant see it , is there any way to look my device's skin on layout editor?
That isn't matter but i wanna see it.
Excuse my english!

Comment: Can you check your AVD and see if the skin option is as what you want it to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click anywhere inside the **Preview** frame and press your keyboard's `F` key.

Comment: Excellent! **Thanks you!**